# How to make a for loop stop at particular value

Tags: python, data-science

I'm creating a NBA Finals simulator that will predict the winner of the NBA finals and the number of games it takes. Heres my current code:

```
def gamesSim(ns):
gamesout = []
team1win = 0
team2win = 0
tie = 0
for i in range(ns):
    gm = gameSim()
    gamesout.append(gm)
    if gm == 1:
        team1win +=1
    elif gm == -1:
        team2win +=1
    elif (team1win == 4 or team2win ==4)
    
    
   
    
print('Team1 Win', team1win/(team1win + team2win+tie), '%')
print('Team2 Win', team2win/(team1win + team2win+tie), '%')
print('Tie' , tie/(team1win + team2win + tie), '%')
return gamesout
```

Here is what it returns:

```
Team1 Win 0.7142857142857143 %
Team2 Win 0.2857142857142857 %
Tie 0.0 %
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
```

The problem is, I want the for loop to end when a team reaches 4 wins. How can I do this?

Comment: To exit a loop you need `break`, but also, you need to change that final `elif` to a new `if` clause.

Answer (score 3):

In order to stop a loop you can use `break`:

```
for i in range(ns):
    gm = gameSim()
    gamesout.append(gm)
    if gm == 1:
        team1win +=1
    elif gm == -1:
        team2win +=1
    elif (team1win == 4 or team2win ==4):
        break
```

Comment: We dont know what are the possible outputs of `gameSim()` other than `1` and `-1`. The code`elif (team1win == 4 or team2win == 4)` may not be reachable at all, if the `gameSim()` function doesnt return other than `1` and `-1`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the proper indentation while posting.

Assuming what I have read correctly, you want to `break` out of `for` loop once either `team1` or `team2` achieves `4` wins. Below is the code.

Short answer, you need to use `break` keyword.

Your code example:

```py
def gamesSim(ns):
    gamesout = []
    team1win = 0
    team2win = 0
    tie = 0
    for i in range(ns):
        if team1win == 4 or team2win == 4:
            break
        gm = gameSim()
        gamesout.append(gm)
        if gm == 1:
            team1win +=1
        elif gm == -1:
            team2win +=1
    print('Team1 Win', team1win/(team1win + team2win+tie), '%')
    print('Team2 Win', team2win/(team1win + team2win+tie), '%')
    print('Tie' , tie/(team1win + team2win + tie), '%')
    return gamesout
```